# In OLS, with a model such as $Y_i=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_i + u_i$, how can I prove $\hat y_i = \hat \beta_1\cdot x_i$?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics

I am reading on OLS method and I am having trouble proving  $\hat y_i = \hat \beta_1\cdot x_i$
I would greatly appreciate any explanation.

Comment: Did you mean $\hat y_i = \hat \beta_0 +  \hat \beta_1 x_i$ ?

Comment: You don't prove it, you assume it (also, what @Henry said)

Comment: Indeed, this is just the *definition* of the predicted value of a regression.